# How to Check if TextView is Empty

Tags: swift

I m a new to Swift. I am trying to check if textView is empty or no user input.

This code seems to work for textField but not textView.

How to solve this issue?

```
this work for textField

var strChking: String = txtField.text

if strChking.isEmpty {

}

This will not work for TextView

var strChkTxtVW: String = txtView.text

if strCkhTxtVW.isEmpty {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to check is the text inside the textView is empty, try this:

```
if txtView.text.isEmpty
```

Comment: I was reading textView class reference in Apple Library . could not find the method. I am very new to iOS. I expect the class library will list property, methods. I sound kind of stupid, can u tell me how to get all the implementations of protocol for textview like : shouldChangeTextInRange and others? I have not clue